Efficient Method to Generate DXF Files from HTML Div Content in Python Django Project
I'm working on a Python Django project where I need to generate DXF files from the content of an HTML div element. The div content can be quite extensive, often exceeding 6000 lines. While I have successfully used the **ezdxf **library to achieve this, the performance is not satisfactory due to the large size of the content and the dynamic nature of the values.
Here are some specifics of my setup and requirements:
Backend Framework: Python Django
Server OS: Windows
Current Approach: Using ezdxf library
Issue: The conversion process is time-consuming and cannot handle dynamic values efficiently.
Are there any libraries or methods that can perform this conversion more efficiently, especially for large HTML content?
How can I optimize the current process to handle dynamic values effectively?
Is there a way to preprocess the HTML content to speed up the DXF generation?
Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Can anybody suggest a method to convert image to dwg/dxf format files using Python?
